# Hoe to rewrite this code to avoid jQuery click deprecated message?

Tags: jquery, click, message, deprecated

Can anybody advise me how to rewrite this piece of js code to avoid the jqmigrate click deprecated warning message?

```
                    return $("<li/>").append($("<a/>", {
                        "class": item["class"],
                        text: item.text,
                        click: function (event) {
                            item.click.call(this, item, event);
                        }
                    }));
```

No matter how I rewrite this code it keeps on telling me JQMIGRATE: jQuery.fn.click() event shorthand is deprecated

If I turn off JQMigrate all works also just fine.

Answer (score 0):

The answer is this

```
            return $("<li/>").append($('<a/>').attr("class", item["class"]).text(item.text).on('click', function(event){item.click(item,event);}));
```